# Using Yii CHtml::ClientChange to Update A Page Element With Form Input Event

Tags: ajax, input, yii

I want to upgrade my current website with Yii Framework.

In the registration form of my application, there is an ajax validation process while let the user know whether the requested ID is available, when user types an ID. Currently it works with onChange attribute of the text input.

I want have the example of the code where anyone did same type of work with Yii framework using CHtml::ClientChange and Form Builder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the [blog tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/) from Yii, it explains step by step how Yii works, and it also has an ajax validation for forms.